# Temperedness of principal series representation of $\mathrm{GL}_2$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, representation-theory

I'm looking for the proof of the following statement:

> Let $\pi = \pi(\chi_1, \chi_2)$ be an (irreducible, admissible, and unitarizable) unramified principal series representation of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ with two (quasi-)characters $\chi_1, \chi_2: \mathbb{Q}^{\times}_p \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$. Then $\pi$ is tempered if and only if $\chi_1, \chi_2$ are unitary characters.

For now, I'm trying to understand the equivalence of Ramanujan's conjecture and temperedness of representations. According to Wikipedia, this is due to Satake, but I couldn't find the original paper. [Gan's lecture note](http://www.cms.zju.edu.cn/UploadFiles/AttachFiles/2004728135246450.pdf) on automorphic forms and automorphic representations has a proof for this (147p-156p), but it assumes the above statement without proof. I also tried to prove it myself but failed. Unitarizable principal series representations are either

- Parabolically induced from unitary characters (i.e. both $\chi_1, \chi_2$ are unitary)

or

- Complementary series representation (i.e. $\chi_1 =\chi_0 \cdot |\cdot|^s$ and $\chi_2 = \chi_0 \cdot | \cdot | ^{-s}$ for some unitary character $\chi_0$ and nonzero $s \in (-1/2, 1/2)$,

and the statement is equivalent to saying that such representations are tempered if and only if it is not complementary series representation. However, I failed to show that the (normalized) matrix coefficients are in $L^{2+\epsilon}(\mathrm{PGL}(\mathbb{Q}_p))$. Could anyone can provide a proof or a reference for the statement? Thanks in advance.